# Any connection between $\operatorname{Ass}_A(M)$ and $\operatorname{Ass}_{A/α}(A/α\otimes_AM)$?

Tags: commutative-algebra

$A$ is noetherian.

When taking quotient of $A$, is there something like taking localization:

> $\operatorname{Ass}_{S^{-1}A}(S^{-1}M)=\operatorname{Spec}(S^{-1}A)\cap \operatorname{Ass}_A(M)$

I’m studying primary decomposition. In this circumstance it’s natural to take quotient rather than localization. Although taking quotient lose some information, I still wonder if there is
any useful connection between $\operatorname{Ass}_A(M)$ and $\operatorname{Ass}_{A/α}(A/α\otimes_AM)$?

Comment: I'm just curious, is the notation $\operatorname{Ass}$ conventional ...?

Comment: @Sisyphus associated points :D